# How to get color from Assets.xcassets?

Tags: objective-c, swift, assets, xcode9, uicolor

I've created Color Set in Assets.xcassets, you can see it in screenshot below

[image]

And my question is

**How to get this color in code ?**

Comment: @Dávid: Color assets are a feature of the Xcode 9 IDE, so the [xcode9] tag makes sense here (I think). On the other hand, it seems to me that the question has been answered before.

Comment: @MartinR now I see, re-added the tag, thanks for the input. And I agree that this seems to be a duplicate actually.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should use this init of UIColor

```
init?(named name: String)
```

For example:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Greeny")
```

And your name of Color in Assets must be the same as parameter in `init`

Comment: or `[UIColor colorNamed:@"yourColor"]` in Objective C